# Webview(1) and Edge

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, azure, webview, microsoft-edge

Edit: After some testing this seems to happen only for a VERY few amount of sites. IE if you navigate to (let's say Bing or Google CPU goes between 4%-12% on that page however if you go to Tik Tok the usage becomes 100% with the Tik Tok Page at 65% +

Edit 2. "Tik tok is not responding due to a long running script" That is what Edge says. I can stop scripts from running.. But they are needed.

About 1 Month ago I created an application that does a lot of "parsing" with DOMS and JS (through WebView1).

There has never been an issue. I know Webview1 is obsolete but I can't imagine what would have changed between 1 week ago and yesterday.

When the application (or even Edge) is running the CPU is at 100%

"(3) Desktop Web Application View" - Remaining CPU - 100%

The application also freezes.

Can anyone think of why? Or know why? This would happen.

Answer (score 0):

I could't figure this out. I ended up switching to webview2 which had none of the issues